# antd ColorPicker mispositioned in modal when the parent page is scrolled down

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I'm currently working on a Next.js project in TypeScript and utilizing Ant Design (AntD) components. I'm facing a peculiar issue with the AntD ColorPicker component when used within a modal.

The problem arises specifically when the parent page is scrolled down, and subsequently, a modal containing the ColorPicker is opened. In this scenario, clicking on a particular position in the ColorPicker results in the selection appearing above the clicked location.

Here is a visual representation of the issue:

[image]

Upon investigating, I observed that this issue occurs only when the parent page has been scrolled down before opening the modal. When the parent page has no scroll, the ColorPicker behaves as expected.

The component structure looks like this:

```
<MyPage>
    <MyModal>
        <ColorPicker/>
    </MyModal>
</MyPage>
```